# Postgres Plus Cloud Database vs Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-rds, enterprisedb

The [Postgres Plus Cloud Database](http://www.enterprisedb.com/cloud-database) was announced early this year.

As I do not have a lot of experience on database clustering, I am wondering which one I should use.  Can anyone give me a compare between Postgres Plus Cloud Database and Amazon RDS in terms of features, cost and maintenance?

The requirements for our applications are:

1. high availability.
2. There will be very low load for our application.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm on the fence with PostgreSQL & MySQL. I want to host with AWS & technically inclined towards PostgreSQL but also want the convenience of RDS :(

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL is not (yet) supported by Amazon RDS. So it's not easy to answer your question.

In any case: Heroku could be an alternative to Postgres Plus Cloud Database.

Comment: The question is asking for a comparison between Postgre Plus Cloud DB on AWS (http://www.enterprisedb.com/cloud-database/amazon) & Amazon's RDS (MySQL). You incorrectly assume that the question is about postgreSQL with RDS.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is now supported in Amazon RDS!

See the blogpost here:

http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2013/11/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-now-available.html?sc_ichannel=EM&sc_icountry=Global&sc_icampaign=reinvent1114&sc_idetail=55698910&ref_=13